# android - HttpUrlConnection don't working

Tags: java, php, android

SO! My friend and I decided to learn a bunch of server + application. Now he has created this page to check the current state of the database - http://java.pareto-marketing.ru/showBD.php She is now empty, and "Json ответ" is null. He also created a php script when connecting to the link

```
http://java.pareto-marketing.ru/chat.php?action=insert&author=Barbara&client=Mike&text=Hello
```

add an entry to the data the author - Barbara, the recipient - Mike, text - Hello. I am trying to connect using HttpUrlConnection, here is my code...

```
try {
URL url = new URL("http://java.pareto-marketing/chat.php?action=insert&author=Barbara&client=Mike&text=Hello");
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
conn.connect();
int res = conn.getResponseCode();
Log.i("chat", "new message!" + res);
} 
catch (Exception e) {
Log.i("chat", "foo" + e.getMessage());
}
finally {
conn.disconnect();
}
```

LogCat - I

```
Displayed ru.diskrim.connect/.MainActivity: +679ms
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You  are send the data in url(That is get method) but you have specified Post in your method type

Comment: @Jois, oh, sorry... could you help me with the codе?

Comment: Sure will upload a answer in a minute

Comment: @Jois, little english, russian programmer.. What? :)

Comment: You should show your php script too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send data using post method, first thing is you need to `setDoOutput(true)`. This means you want to send a request body.

Next you will have to use **DataOutputStream** for controlling the output. We can do multiple operation on output stream using **DataOutputStream**. It also helps us to write primitive Java data types to an output stream.

```
  JSONObject urlParameters = new JSONObject();
    jsonParam.put("action", "insert");
    jsonParam.put("author", "barbara");
    jsonParam.put("client", "mike");
   jsonParam.put("text", "hello");

//Send request
  DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
              conn.getOutputStream ());
  wr.writeBytes (URLEncoder.encode(urlParameters.toString(),"UTF-8");
  wr.flush ();
  wr.close ();
```

urlParameters contain your parameter.

This way you can send post data to your server.

Comment: Actually this how you post data using httpUrlConnection. Try using volley

Answer (score 0):

You need to use :

```
conn.setDoOutput(true);
```

if you want to use method **POST** or **PUT**. Set it to false if you use **GET**